# Execute command in entity with potion effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want that a mob take damage if it have the water_breathing potion effect.

```
/effect @e[<mob with water_breathing>] instant_damage 1 1
```

So, how I execute a command in a mob with a specific potion effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assign a label based on the mob's NBT data using `/scoreboard` first, and then target based on that label:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Creeper,tag=wb] remove wb
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Creeper] add wb {ActiveEffects:[{Id:13b}]}

/effect @e[type=Creeper,tag=wb] minecraft:instant_damage 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in just one command in Minecraft 1.13

```
/effect give @e[type=creeper,nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:13b]}] instant_damage 1 1
```